# Virtual page view issues -datalayer- GTM

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm working with this preebuild ecommerce system, all of the checkout is in an iframe. And the event below is pushed at every major step, 'checkout 1','checkout 2','payment details' and 'transaction complete' page & title reflects each steps. But NOTE the event name 'VirtualPageview' is the same for all steps mentioned above.

```
{
event: 'VirtualPageview',
page: '/Test/test',
title 'test | test',
gtm.uniqueEventId:25
}
```

Visual in gtm debugger:
https://gyazo.com/6356cc13f6b63cad73e55d10abc90154

Now i'm wondering if there is any way to track this as pageviews in analytics? (My primary goal is to create a funnel visualization)

I've read through so much information and as a beginner i'm quite overwhelmed, i would appreciate a little info to point me in the right direction.

Here is what i've done this far, not sure if i'm on the right path.
I feel limited with this setup, because the trigger will trigger on all steps because event name is the same, that would be fine if i could somehow grab page and page title from datalayer dynamically.

- GTM TAG

https://gyazo.com/6f7ea35307bca9694835359485b9f74d

- GTM Trigger

https://gyazo.com/4c3b489f627dd72e17816e5b5f61f299

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a DataLayer variable called `page` and another called `title` (names of your variables) and use them as field values like this: `{{page}}`